# Как правильно сравнить два столбца в Excel файлах при помощи Python? Как выбрать значения из File2.xlsx которых нет File1.xlsx?

Tags: python, excel

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой, есть 2 файла File1.xlsx и File2.xlsx необходимо сравнить значения ячеек выбранного столбца из второго файла с первым. Выбрать значения из File2.xlsx которых нет File1.xlsx. Для этого я сравниваю значения поэлементно, однако если количество строк в File1.xlsx меньше чем в File2.xlsx алгоритм не работает.

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file_old = xlrd.open_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet_old = excel_data_file_old.sheet_by_index(0)
excel_data_file_new = xlrd.open_workbook('file2.xlsx')
sheet_new = excel_data_file_new.sheet_by_index(0)

row_number_old = sheet_old.nrows
row_number_new = sheet_new.nrows

for i in range(0,row_number_old):
    cellVal1 = sheet_old.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=0)
    for j in range(0,row_number_new):
        cellVal2 = sheet_new.cell_value(rowx=j, colx=0)
        if cellVal1 == cellVal2:
            break            
    else:
       print(cellVal2)
```

Comment: а если прочитать все значения из первого и второго файла в переменные, а потом сравнить их с помощью `set()`?

Comment: спасибо, да так работает, записываем значения 1го файла a.add(sheet_old.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=0)) а потом в цикле проверяем  if cellVal2 not in a:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#excel):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\f1.xlsx', parse_cols='A', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\f2.xlsx', parse_cols='A', header=None)

print(df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])])
```

Некоторые пояснения:

Сначала мы читаем только интересующие нас столбцы в Pandas.DataFrame и получаем след. DataFrame's (DFs):

```
In [19]: df1
Out[19]:
    0
0  11
1   2
2  33
3   4
4  55
5   6

In [20]: df2
Out[20]:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
```

Проверяем какие значения из столбца `0` в `df1` содержатся в `df2[0]`:

```
In [21]: df1[0].isin(df2[0])
Out[21]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

логическое отрицание (т.е. инвертируем логические значения):

```
In [22]: ~df1[0].isin(df2[0])
Out[22]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

выбираем те значения из `df1[0]` которые отсутствуют в `df2[0]`:

```
In [23]: df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])]
Out[23]:
    0
0  11
2  33
4  55
```

Comment: вы молодец, заменили 11 строчек кода 4 -  мя!!! может подскажите как при помощи Pandas форматировать ячейки в файле по этому условию?!

Comment: а что именно вы хотите сделать? как отформатировать?

Comment: например, ячейки значения которых df1[0] которые отсутствуют в df2[0]  выделить  заливкой

Comment: Вы можете задать отдельный (новый) вопрос с небольшими примерами таблиц (можно в виде CSV или выложить куда-нибудь ссылки на примеры Excel файлов)?

Comment: не совсем понял Вас, создать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @МихаилКовалев, задать новый вопрос на StackOverflow. Изменение существующих вопросов - плохая практика, т.к. измененный вопрос часто делает уже данные ответы либо неправильными либо неполными

Comment: @МихаилКовалев, я ответил на [ваш вопрос в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532649/python-how-to-excel-paint-the-background-cells), поэтому наверное нет смысла создавать такой же вопрос в русскоязычной версии SO

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file1 = xlrd.open_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet1 = excel_data_file1.sheet_by_index(0)

excel_data_file2 = xlrd.open_workbook('file2.xlsx')
sheet2 = excel_data_file2.sheet_by_index(0)

col1 = sheet1.col(colx=0)
col2 = sheet2.col(colx=0)

def values(column):
    return set(cell.value for cell in column)

diff = values(col2) - values(col1)

print(diff)
```

вот что в итоге получилась у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прочитать столбец, можно использовать `col = sheet.col(colx)`.  Для сравнения столбцов, выполните:

```
def equal_values(col1, col2):
    return (len(col1) == len(col2)
            and all(cell1.value == cell2.value for cell1, cell2 in zip(col1, col2)))
```

`equal_values(col1, col2)` возвращает `True` если значения ячеек в столбцах col1 и col2 совпадают и `False` в противном случае (порядок ячеек имеет значение).

Чтобы найти значения ячеек, которые есть в col2, но нет в col1, игнорируя порядок ячеек:

```
def values(column):
    return set(cell.value for cell in column)

diff = values(col2) - values(col1)
```

Comment: спасибо, но количество элементов в col1 и col2 разное. А выбрать необходимо значения cell2.value которых нет в col1

Comment: @МихаилКовалев Мой ответ показывает как **сравнить** два столбца. Что вы думаете len() функция делает? Зачем она в ответе используется?

Comment: функция показывает длину?!

Comment: @МихаилКовалев верно. Я добавил объяснение, что выражение означает и показал как явную разницу можно найти между столбцами

Comment: спасибо большое !!!